# Win8/VS2012: Cannot open include file 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012, freeglut, glew

I'm trying to migrate from Windows 7 to 8, but glew and freeglut are giving me problems.

The instructions I used were basically as follows:

1) Copy the contents of Lib and Include\GL folders of libraries to Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\[latest version] Lib and Include\GL folders

2) Copy freeglut.dll and the content of glew's bin folder to Windows\SysWOW64\

This worked fine using Windows 7/VS2010 (where the folder in Microsoft SDKs was v7.0A), but on Windows 8/VS2012, I'm getting the following error when building my solution:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
```

For the SDKs folder, on Windows 8, the latest version is v8.0A, however, I've tried using the v7.0A as well, getting the same outcome. I did notice, however, that in Windows 7, the SDKs folder had the Lib and Include folders, but the Windows 8 folder did not. Not sure if this matters.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
The instructions I'm using for installation are a slight modification of the ones found [here](http://openglbook.com/setting-up-opengl-glew-and-freeglut-in-visual-c/), with the modification being copying the dll's into Windows' system folder instead of into each project output (which doesn't seem to help, either).

The applications I'm developing is for a college course, so using other libraries is likely to be out of the question.

The versions of the libraries are 2.8.0 (freeglut) and 1.9.0 32-bit (glew).

Answer (score 3):

It is my understanding that GLEW and GLUT have been dropped from the latest SDKs. They were awfully out of date anyways. You can grab the latest headers and libraries from [here](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) then integrate them with your project in the usual way.

Comment: You may want to use [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/news.php) instead though. It has almost exactly the same API as GLUT so you can use it interchangeably, but is better maintained.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your answer. The instructions I'm using for installing are a slight modification of [these](http://openglbook.com/setting-up-opengl-glew-and-freeglut-in-visual-c/), with the modifications being copying the dll's into Windows' system folder instead of into each project (which doesn't seem to work either). Also, I'm using this for a college course, so using other libraries are probably not an option. I'll update the question with this.